# Jquery: Select class where $(this) is

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to select a div using its class, but there are other divs with the same class and with the same buttons that trigger my function, so I only want to select the class where $(this) is in.

I tried .parent, .child, .contains, .find but I didn't figure it out...

```js
$(".btt_class").click(function() {
  
  // I know this is wrong, but to give an idea of what I need
  $(".div_class").has(this).append("You cliked here");
  
});
```

```html
<div class="div_class">
  <input class="btt_class" type="button" value="Click me" />
</div>

<div class="div_class">
  <input class="btt_class" type="button" value="Click me" />
</div>
```

Comment: unclear what you're trying to do. you want the button to say "you clicked here" after it's clicked? what is supposed to say "you clicked here"?

Comment: And what's `$(this)` supposed to be? A piece of string? Where it's located within the element?

Comment: @Pamblan The "you clicked here" is an exemple to see if it works, it must show this text only inside the div of the button you clicked, not the other div that has the same class.

Comment: $(this) is the button you clicked, if I do  $(this).hide(); it will only hide the clicked button and not the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your request correctly, your snippet does just what you described: selecting the div, the currently clicked button is in and appending some text to it:

Pleas check out https://jsfiddle.net/4qwy605p/

```
$(".btt_class").click(function() {

  $(".div_class").has(this).append("You cliked here");

});

<div class="div_class">
  <input class="btt_class" type="button" value="Click me" />
</div>

<div class="div_class">
  <input class="btt_class" type="button" value="Click me" />
</div>
```

It works as requested in the fiddle.

Is it possible you just forgot to load jQuery in your snippet?

Comment: is the <script> code before or after the <div>? Also, are you wrapping your jQuery code in `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Well at least the snippet you provided causes an Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined ... it is not working there because there is no jQuery loaded. If it is on your site, there might be a different error occurring, causing the script to stop before your the code you provided is executed

Comment: The script is after and inside $(document).ready(function() {}, all the other Jquery works. The click function is triggered.

Comment: I loaded the simple question example, and it works on my site so there must be an error of some kind in the html because is much more complex than that. So as far as the question concerns, it's solved XD

Answer (score 1):

To capture the element of the button being clicked you can do this:

```
$(".btt_class").click(function() {

  $this = $(this);  // captures the input element
  $div_class_elem = $this.parent();  // goes up one level/element to capture the div element

  $div_class_elem.append("You clicked here");  // append this text to the end of the div element

});
```

Comment: Not as elegant a solution as the thread starter was looking for, but perfectly working for the given example. Keep in mind though that this would only work for the exact structure as fiven in the example. In case the structure would change in the future, the code would have to be adapted. Therefore the approach to use .has() might still be the best choice

Comment: Thank you for the positive input, to elaborate I made it less condensed so I could spell out the steps and comment them - I will leave it up to the OP if he wants to combine this with other solutions

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick: (OOPS, edited to include finding the closest one.)

```
 $(".btt_class").on("click",function(){
      myDiv = $(this).parent().closest('div.div_class');
      myDiv.append("You clicked here");
    });
```

Comment: how so? adding the closest() tag ensures that if, in a code revision, the user wraps the button another element, the intermediate element isn't the thing that gets appended.

...in fact, i'd say that i didn't go far enough with the specificity  - it should be .closest('div.div_class'), in the interest of speed.

Comment: true, but then you don't really need `parent()`

Answer (score 0):

Use .closest() to traverse up the DOM tree up to the specified selector. This should do the trick:

```
$(this).parent().closest('div').append("You clicked here!")
```

Comment: this will go one level above where OP wants...and may not even do anything if there is no div above there ... get rid of `parent()` or get rid of `closest()`

Comment: that's what i thought too, but this actually works, though not the easiest or most efficient way to do it.

Comment: @Pamblam  ok... right, because closest does start at  element passed to it  which would be the parent. Still ugly though